# How to find WebElement within WebElement with WebdriverJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriverjs

If this is the HTML

```
<div>
 <div>
  <p class="my-element"></p>
 </div>
<div>
<div>
 <div>
   <p class="the-text"> I want to get this text</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <p class="another-element"></p>
 </div>
<div>
<div>
 <div>
   <p class="the-text"> I DONT want to get this text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

and my el is

`var el = el.findElement(By.css(".my-element"))`;

how can I get the p.the-text text?

I need a jquery equivalent of

```
el.parent().parent().find(".the-text")
```

Comment: That jquery won't even work here because, at least with the HTML provided, there is no parent of both elements. Is this the correct HTML? btw. you didn't close a couple divs. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element with a single css selector and use `getText()`

```
driver.findElement( By.css( '.the-text' ) ).getText( function(textDisplayed ) {
   console.log( textDisplayed ); 
} );
```